# Keeping 2 filepointers for a file in C# as index to file content

Tags: c#, file, filestream, file-handling

We create Fstream1 which opens the file and stores the start of file.
Now we copy the fstream1 to fstream2.

Note: `fstream1` will read file upwards whereas fstream2 will read file downwards.

Before reading a chunk of data upwards or downwards the respective `fstream*` has to remember the initial start position.

Problem is when we read the position of both the fstream’s is moving leading to loss of the position intended to store.

Example: Consider initial `fstream1.pos = 500` & `fstream2.pos =500`. Now if I read upwards 200 characters the `fstream1.pos=300` but `fstream2.pos` should remain 500, in our case the `fstream2.pos` also becomes 300. 
Similarly if I read downwards.

```
fileStream1 = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 1, true);
fileStream2 = filestream1; // want this but without opening the file again
```

considering `filestream` would be like `filepointers` in C++.
Note: above task is in C#.

Comment: `fileStream2 = filestream1;` actually just copies the reference to the same object, and all further manipulaions are being done on the **same object**.

Comment: yes. Exactly. I want them to exist individually so that I can move the positions as per my requirement.

Comment: I don't think you can have seperate file streams without opening the file twice. Why is it bad when you open the file a second time?

Comment: Opening the file twice would be easy solution but its not good because the file is dynamically being updated so might result in problems.

Comment: @tusharpandey Well, if the file content is modified you will have a problem either way. Just open the file twice and see how this works.

Comment: @helb I am gonna try that too. The advantage here I think is that there is 1 stream only so the data it will have will be intact.Whereas in case of two streams the content read could differ. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Change your `share` parameter to `FileShare.Read`.  Then writes won't be allowed while your program has the file open.

Comment: Your other option would be to read the entire file in to memory (copy it to a `MemoryStream`), then you are guaranteed that any updates to the filesystem won't affect your running program.

Comment: @Sam Won't that be a blocking call. I mean if the process updating the file tries to write it when I have opened the file, opening would not be allowed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you would scan upwards or downwards on a file to locate a position int he file faster, I would suggest: -

1) Open the file once.

2) Keep two variables - UpPointer & DownPointer and initial them as UpPointer = DownPointer = 500 (from your example).

3) When a read or scan is made, update the respective pointer.